# What is the structure on SUV's top back edge?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, flow, aerodynamics, turbulence

I see a lot of SUV's that  has the structure as shown in the picture .I am talking about the the top back edge (right above the back window).

Wont't it worsen the streamlined design and causing more drag?

What's the benefit of this structure?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You understand, I hope, that the main purpose of such a thing is to speed the car off the showroom floor. Race cars have little "wings" to produce down-force so they can get around turns faster. But the real point is - race cars look really cool, don't they? So if you put those little things on a car, they have the effect of vacuuming the buyer's wallet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't related to physics

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a spoiler.

> A rear spoiler usually comes standard in most sports vehicles and resembles the shape of a raised wing in the rear of the vehicle. The main purpose of a rear spoiler in a vehicle's design is to counteract lift, thereby increasing stability at higher speeds. In order to achieve the lowest possible drag, air must flow around the streamlined body of the vehicle without coming into contact with any areas of possible turbulence. A rear spoiler design that stands off the rear deck lid will increase downforce, reducing lift at high speeds while incurring a drag penalty.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_drag_coefficient

Answer (score 1):

at the speeds at which an SUV travels, the aerodynamic effect of these "spoilers" is minimal. They serve to deflect airflow above the rear hatch in such a way as to minimize dirt and mud buildup on the rear hatch glass.

Comment: Back in prehistory (the 1980's) I owned a big old station wagon that had an air deflector to push air down over the rear window to clear water off in the rain. A rear wiper would have worked better, but I guess the deflector was cheaper...

Comment: I remember those too, as a passenger. GM products had them. Fords drew air in from the sides( 1965-67 galaxie wagons).

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. I thought there would be less rain and dust buildup without that thing, just like most sedans with better-streamlined design. This design makes the buildup issue worse so that SUV's usually need a rear wiper. Any articles about this thing helping with that? Thanks